# Baixar arquivo da web para função em PHP

Tags: php, arquivo-zip

Eu estou usando a classe ZipArchive do PHP para descompactar arquivos do meu diretório, porém meu arquivo é atualizado semanalmente no mesmo endereço da web. Eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('http://example.com/file.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('C:/xampp/htdocs');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
} ?>
```

E ele cai diretamente do `else` retornando a falha. Existe alguma classe que faça o download do arquivo para o meu diretório e então utilize a ZipArchive corretamente?

Comment: `ftp` se precisar de autenticação ou `curl` ou ainda um código de um pacote http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/ então tudo depende ... o open do `ZipArchive` abre um arquivo local de diretório.

Comment: Obrigado @VirgilioNovic pesquisando sobre curl eu consegui resolver 100% do meu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando a dica do Virgilio e usando `curl` eu consegui adaptar meu código que atendeu todas as minhas necessidades, talvez sirva para quem busque o mesmo:

```
  <?php 
        $url = "http://www.example.com/file.zip"; // URL of what you wan to download
        $zipFile = "file.zip"; 
        $extractDir = "extracted"; 
        $zipResource = fopen($zipFile, "w");
    
        // Get The Zip File From Server
        $ch = curl_init();
    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $zipResource);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
    
        $page = curl_exec($ch);
    
        if(!$page) {
            echo "Error :- ".curl_error($ch);
        }
    
        curl_close($ch);
    
        /* Open the Zip file */
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $extractPath = $extractDir;
    
        if($zip->open($zipFile) != "true"){
            echo "Error :- Unable to open the Zip File";
        } 
    
        /* Extract Zip File */
        $zip->extractTo($extractPath);
        $zip->close();
    
        die('Your file was downloaded and extracted, go check.');
    ?>
```